How to manage single instance only in sch file using tivoli job?
Problem statement: Job should run every 5 mins in 24*7 with single instance but i am seeing next day tivoli is running with multiple instance. How can make sure single instance should run all time.
like-
 1 day = 1 instance
 2 day = 2 instance
 .....  etc.

Script:
SCHEDULE HOST#A
 DESCRIPTION "Schedule a job every 5 minutes"
 ON RUNCYCLE DAILY "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
:
HOST#A_DEF
  EVERY 0005
END 

